# Use JQmobile for CSS-based columns with size 30%-70%

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I can use the Two column grids `ui-grid-a`, or three... that display 50%-50% but how can i display a row with sizes like **70%-30%.** So text from right side be on the 30% - the `a grid` and the `b grid` 70%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add custom css to override the JQM defaults, as follows:

```
.ui-block-a {
      width: 70% !important;
}

.ui-block-b {
      width: 30% !important;
}
```

**JSBin - example**
http://jsbin.com/eguwij/2/edit#source

Comment: OK it's what i wanted,and how i change it so it start to write from right side and not left (not English)

Comment: @Igor I'm sorry I can't answer that RTL question, no experience on that. You may want to ask a separate question.